# How to make the following edit to an XML file?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML file encoded in UTF-8 similar to the one below and need to update it conditionally using PowerShell

```
<Group>
    <Entry>
        <String>
            <User>UserOne</User>
        </String>
        <String>
            <Key>URL</Key>
            <Value>Test</Value>
        </String>
    </Entry>
   <Entry>
       <String>
           <User>UserTwo</User>
       </String>
      <String>
          <Key>URL</Key>
          <Value></Value>
      </String>
   </Entry>
</Group>
```

I need to update those URLs who have a "blank" Value to a predetermined text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, but I suspect there will be better solutions.

```bsh
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content .\Desktop\test.xml -Raw)
$urls = $xml.SelectNodes("//Key") | Where-Object { $_.InnerText -eq "URL" }
foreach ($url in $urls) {
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($url.NextSibling.InnerText)) {
        $url.NextSibling.InnerText = "predetermined text"
    }
}
$xml.Save(".\Desktop\test.xml")
```

Comment: Why do `$null -eq $url.NextSibling.InnerText` when your already doing `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($url.NextSibling.InnerText)`?

Comment: Bad habit of doing both when I write PowerShell. It's all strings in the XML, so of course it's not necessary here. Thanks for calling me out on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can inspire from that, but not better than @ash answer :

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<Group>
    <Entry>
        <String>
            <User>UserOne</User>
        </String>
        <String>
            <Key>URL</Key>
            <Value>Test</Value>
        </String>
    </Entry>
   <Entry>
       <String>
           <User>UserTwo</User>
       </String>
      <String>
          <Key>URL</Key>
          <Value></Value>
      </String>
   </Entry>
</Group>
"@

$users = $xml.selectNodes("//Group/Entry") 
foreach ($user in $users)
{
  Write-Host "Enter URL for $($user.String[0].User)"
  $url = Read-Host
  $user.String[1].Value  = [string]$url
}

$xml.Save("c:\temp\FileAfter.xml")
```